# Multi Line TextBox text alignment (C# 2.0)

Tags: c#, textbox, alignment

I have Multi Line TextBox (C# 2.0). I want to display some data as follows.

```
"Contact Person    : "  + string1 + Environment.NewLine
"Sales Man         : "  + string2 + Environment.NewLine
"Credit Limit      : "  + string3 + Environment.NewLine
"Due days          : "  + string4 + Environment.NewLine
```

But this code displaying as

```
Contact Person    :   Person1
Sales Man        :   salesman1
Credit Limit :  50000.00 
Due days       : 20
```

My problem is I can't align the text. My expected out put,

```
Contact Person    : Person1
Sales Man         : salesman1
Credit Limit      : 50000.00 
Due days          : 20
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the font used by the textbox to a monospaced (non-proportional) font, like Courier.

Comment: +1 This is what you need to do.  I would probably use String.Format also, but thats just personal preference.

Comment: I Checked with String.Format function. It also not working well. There is no other facility to do this ????

Answer (score 0):

Set the AcceptsTab property of your textBox to true. Then use '\t' in your textlines to tab to the correct position.